# template.Execute doesn't pass data

Tags: go

I did the same thing that lecture showed.
but there is no template expansion occurring in the output, whereas I expect to see the names in `sages` to be inserted into the output html.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    sages := []string{"MLK", "Jesus", "Buddha"}
    err := tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, sages)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

`index.gohtml` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {{range .}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The output can be [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUjAb.png).

Comment: Whats `index.gohtml`s file encoding?

Comment: @tkausl how to see it ? can't find in properties

Comment: Check Visual Studio Code's status bar (bottom): http://prntscr.com/uwqjby

Comment: @tkasul thanks that's the matter. how to set utf-8 as the default? should I change powershell or just in vscode?

Comment: @flython you need to configure your editor (vscode) to save in utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `text/template` where you should be using `html/template` but that's not causing the issue.

It's hard to reproduce from an image, but given the double-spaced output I guess your template file has been saved in utf-16 whereas go is expecting utf-8. Given your input file has characters only from low-numbered unicode code points, that will result in alternating 0 bytes and the actual bytes from the input.

Comment: I tried writing chcp 65001 and executing go run main.go , but still same what should I do?